# Expanding a list of numbers into a matrix (list with n values to multiply to a n x n matrix)

Tags: r, matrix

I have a set of numbers, which I want to expand into a matrix.
There are 4 values in the list which I want to expand into a 4x4 matrix.
Here is some example data

```
freq <- c(627,449,813,111)
```

I want to expand this into a matrix of so that it's like this.
Apologies I have just copied and pasted data, thus it's not an R output, but hope it helps to get the idea across.

```
    1   2   3   4   Total
1   197 141 255 35  627
2   141 101 183 25  449
3   255 183 330 45  813
4   35  25  45  6   111
    627 449 813 111 2000
```

The cells are multiplication of the (row total)x(column total)/(table total). The value in 1,1 = (627 x 627)/2000 = 197. The value in 2,1 = (627 x 449)/2000 = 141, and so on.

Is there a function that will create this matrix? I will try to do it via a loop but was hoping there is a function or matrix calculation trick that can do this more efficiently? Apologies if I didn't articulate the above too well, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
freq <- c(627,449,813,111) 
round(outer(freq, freq)/sum(freq))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]  197  141  255   35
#> [2,]  141  101  183   25
#> [3,]  255  183  330   45
#> [4,]   35   25   45    6
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter here, but it is good practice to avoid constructions like `outer(x, x) / sum(x)` in favour of ones like `tcrossprod(x / sqrt(sum(x)))`:

```r
round(tcrossprod(freq / sqrt(sum(freq))))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]  197  141  255   35
## [2,]  141  101  183   25
## [3,]  255  183  330   45
## [4,]   35   25   45    6
```

There are a few issues with the `outer` approach:

- `outer(x, x)` evaluates `tcrossprod(as.vector(x), as.vector(x))` internally. The `as.vector` calls and everything else that happens inside of `outer` are completely redundant if `x` is already a vector. The `as.vector` calls are actually worse than redundant: if `x` has any attributes, then `as.vector(x)` requires a deep copy of `x`.
- Naively doing `A <- outer(x, x); A / sum(x)` requires R to allocate memory for *two* `n`-by-`n` matrices. For large enough `n`, that can be quite wasteful, if not impossible. R is clever enough to avoid the second allocation if you compute `outer(x, x) / sum(x)` directly. However, such optimizations are low level, come with a number of gotchas, and are not even documented in `?Arithmetic`, so it can be unsafe to rely on them.
- `outer(x, x)` can result in underflow or overflow if the elements of `x` are very (very) small or large.

`tcrossprod(x / sqrt(sum(x)))` avoids all of these issues by scaling `x` *before* computing an outer product and cutting out all of the redundancies of `outer`.

Comment: thanks for this advice, I can definitely use this method, when there I have to deal with much larger list of numbers. Thanks very much